# Is there a windows live php sdk?

Tags: php, sdk, hotmail, windows-live

Hi
I have been looking for a php sdk for windows live but could not find one. I found only an asp.net sdk, is there a php sdk for this service? and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft won't make an SDK for a language they haven't made (which is silly, but beside the point). There might be a a 3rd party SDK out there for PHP, but it's unlikely too; if you want to work with Microsoft stuff then, in this case, C# is your only option (asp.net), or another more obscure option possibly.

James

Comment: Somehow I knew it. My guess is that I can look at the asp.net SDK and try to work out a PHP alternative, or find a third party SDK for PHP. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem :-) it's a shame M$ aren't more open to better technologies than their own to be honest... as I write this on IE 8. Truly shocking software.com!